# How to make this numbers triangle using nested while loops? (python 2.7)

Tags: python-2.7

i have tried to make this pattern with the code given below....i know it needs further changing but can't figure out what?

[Number Triangle](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vP2WF.png)

```
 n=5
 m=1
 while n>=1:
     while m<=5:
       print " "*(n),m
       n=n-1
       m=m+1
```

i want an ouput like this:

```
    1
   22
  333
 4444
55555
```

Comment: What is your expected output? This will make it easier for people to answer.

Comment: i have added picture named "Number Triangle" thought it would display a pic instead of link....let me fix that...thanks for the reply

Comment: kindly see the posted link.....i cant post images without 10 reputation

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do you require nested loops?

```
>>> n=5
>>> for i in range(1, n+1):
...     print("{:>{width}}".format(str(i)*i, width=n))
    1
   22
  333
 4444
55555
```

But to fix your code - you are missing the multiplier on your number:

```
n=5
m=1
while n>=1:
    while m<=5:
        print " "*(n), str(m)*m
        n=n-1
        m=m+1
```

Comment: im starting out in python and learning loops currently....thanks for fixing the code.....i couldnt figure out the multiplier..thanks :)

Comment: but is there a way to do it without using any built-in functions?

Comment: Not sure what you mean, without `print`, `str`?

Comment: without using str ..print is fine though

Comment: Not really, without really complicating things, `print` calls the same thing as `str(m)` to turn any python object into a printable value. Using the language's standard functions seems to me part of learning the language.

Comment: `str(m)` just turns the `4` into `"4"` which you can then multiply `"4"*4 = "4444"`, whereas `4*4 = 16`.